# fork() and waitpid() not waiting for child

Tags: c++, linux, multiprocessing, posix, waitpid

I am having a bit of trouble getting waitpid to work could someone please explain what is wrong with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filename_memory;
    decltype(fork()) pid;

    if (!(pid = fork())) {
        cout << "in child" << endl;
        sleep(1);
    }

    else {
        int status_child;

        do {
            waitpid(pid, &status_child, WNOHANG);
            cout << "waiting for child to finish" << endl;
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status_child));

        cout << "child finished" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to check the return value of `waitpid` and read the `status_child` only if the return value equals `pid`, something like `if (ret == pid && WIFEXITED(status_child)) break;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If wait() or waitpid() returns because the status of a child process
>   is available, these functions shall return a value equal to the
>   process ID of the child process for which status is reported.
>
> If waitpid() was invoked with WNOHANG set in options, it has at least
>   one child process specified by pid for which status is not available,
>   and status is not available for any process specified by pid, 0 is
>   returned. Otherwise, (pid_t)-1 shall be returned, and errno set to
>   indicate the error.

This means that the `status_child` variable has no meaning until `waitpid` returns the pid of the child.

You can fix this by applying these changes:

```
int ret;
do {
    ret = waitpid(pid, &status_child, WNOHANG);
    cout << "waiting for child to finish" << endl;
} while (ret != pid || !WIFEXITED(status_child));

cout << "child finished" << endl;
```